# Error on trying to mock out ToString() with Typemock on a Guid

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock, typemock-isolator

I am writing some unit tests and I want to mock out a user `hmGuid`.  To do so I do the following.

```
string userGuidString = "b3830ce8-09aa-41ac-b759-d2af4388c706";
Guid hmGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => hmGuid.ToString()).WillReturn(userGuidString);
```

However when I do that I get the following error

```
No method calls found in recording block. Please check:

Are you trying to fake a field instead of a property? try to set field
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  The `ToString()` is pretty standard and I've been able to mock this out on other classes before

Comment: So you're telling typemock that when ToString() is called on a specific Guid instance, then a particular value is returned, which seems an odd way to do things. Is this the actual problem you're facing, or just an illustration of it?

Comment: This is the actual problem, and why is that an odd way to do things? I want to test code that uses the hmGuid string and this is an easy way to get a consistent one

Comment: Isn't  `Guid hmGuid = new Guid("b3830ce8-09aa-41ac-b759-d2af4388c706");` easier?

Comment: That would be for this case sure, but the problem remains with Typemock just the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: i work at typemock

The problem with your test is not the ToString() method, it's that you are trying to modify the behavior of a `Mscorlib` class, `Guid`, and it's not supported for the moment, but it will be possible in the near future.

More information [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fsupportedfakeablemscorlibtypes.htm).